# Restore application state using ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory

Tags: windows, save, state, restore

Before spending several hours to hit a dead end, I thought I should consult the experts here.  I want to have a background app in Win32 which can capture the memory of other apps and dump it to a text file, then have the background app restore the app to it's exact state.

It seems like ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory are functions that were created specifically for that.  I understand new memory addresses will have to be created, but is there any reason why using WriteProcessMemory with new addresses could not do this?  If you completely replace the process's memory, it should bring it back, right?  Even if the app was closed and reopened using CreateProcess, you should get the exact same state when you completely rewrite the process's memory with WriteProcessMemory.  Would the newly created addresses know how to point to each other, or is there any way to "make them know"?

Please shed some light on this to me.  Thanks to all.

Comment: OK, so you reset the contents of the application's memory to a previous state.  What about the flow of execution?  Unless you're incredibly lucky, the instruction pointer (or pointers, since there's probably multiple threads) will be in the wrong place.  Plus of course any handles that have been closed in the meantime won't be valid, the GUI state will be inconsistent, etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks Harry.  Does Read/WriteProcessMemory gather everything about the process including threads?  If no, what if I recreated the threads as well using similar api functions, wouldn't the dump(s) when restored overwrite everything about the process including GUI state?  All that's left then is to find a way to make the pointers point back to the new locations, right?  If there's absolutely no way to do that, then case closed.

Comment: There are I believe debugging functions that can be used to query and set the thread context.  But the GUI state isn't independent of the rest of the system.  If you revert the state of a single program without simultaneously reverting the state of every other program in the same session (and of the operating system itself) it will no longer be consistent.  Similarly with kernel handles, the application's view of what handles it has open has to remain consistent with the kernel's view of what handles the application has open.

Comment: Perfect.  That's the type of bad and good news I was looking for.  Thanks Harry.